# STM32 Current Flash Vector Address

Tags: memory, stm32, ram, bootloader, flash-memory

I'm working on a dual OS system with STM32F103, I have two separate program that programmed on different FLASH locations. if both of the programs are the same, the only way to know which of them running is just by its start vector address.
But How I Can Read The Current Program Start Vector Address in STM32 ???

Comment: Do both programs set SCB->VTOR to something different?

Comment: actually, I split the FLASH into two space and I have a program that is running and it can update itself. it'll download new firmware to another location in the FLASH and relocate START VECTOR. and the programme will start from the upper address in the FLASH. but next time that the new firmware wants to update itself, it must use the lower address of the FLASH for writing the new firmware. the address that filled by old firmware. and then change the start vector to lower address. then I need to know where the current program is programmed?! upper or lower section on the FLASH?

Comment: That sounds complicated. The way I have done this in the past is have the updater write to image #2, and the bootloader check the crc of image #2 and if it's different to the crc of image #1 it copies #2 over #1. That way the code is always running in the same place and image #1 is always the one which is executed.

Comment: Doing it the way you plan at the moment, you will need to know when the program is linked whether it will be running from High or Low flash, there's much more to go wrong.

Comment: you mean it'll be better to write a bootloader that can check CRC of both images and if they have a difference then copy upper one into lower?

Comment: and just add a write section in my code, for writing in the upper section then restart the MCU for staring bootloader and update lower section image.

Comment: that sounds good... but, how I must know about new firmware length and it's CRC's position?

Comment: Have a fixed size for your image, and keep the crc at a fixed location within it.

Comment: I wonder if you could use inline assembly to read the link register (LR) or main stack pointer (MSP) and determine which region that address belongs to (program 1 or program 2).

Comment: @mban The link register could help, I doubt the stack pointer would be of much use though, i would assume both applications would use the whole RAM area.

Comment: $Colin , can you give me a sample code? I'm a little confused!

Comment: Actually, I got my HEX file and decode it in INTEL HEX format. now I have address and value to write on the Flash. but can I ignore the addresses and write all data sequentially? 
another question is that, after writing these data on the flash is there any other thing that I must to do? or just restart the chip!

Answer (score 1):

After reading the comments, it sounds like what you have/want is a bootloader.  If your goal here is to have two different applications, one to do your main processing and real time handling and the other to just program new firmware, then you want to make a bootloader in your default boot flash space.

Bootloaders fundamentally do a few things, everything else is extra.

1. Check itself using some type of data integrity check like a CRC.
2. Checks the application
3. Jumps to the application.

Bootloaders will also program applications in the app space and verify they are programmed correctly before jumping as well.  Colin gave some good advice about appending a CRC to the hex file before it is programmed in flash space to verify the applications.

There are a few things to look out for.  The first would be the linker script and this is extremely important.  A linker script will be used to map input objects to output objects and then determine based upon that script, what memory space they go into.  For both of your applications, you need to create a memory map of how you want both programs to sit inside of the flash space.  From this point, you can then make linker scripts for both programs so that a hex file can be generated within the parameters of what you deem acceptable flash space for the program.  Each project you have will have its own linker script.  An example would look something like this:

```
  LR_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00010000  {    ; load region size_region
  ER_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00010000  {  ; load address = execution address
   *.o (RESET, +First)
   *(InRoot$$Sections)
   .ANY (+RO)
  }
  RW_IRAM1 0x20000000 0x00018000  {  ; RW data
   .ANY (+RW +ZI)
  }
}
```

This will give RAM for the application to use as well as a starting point for the application.

After that, you can start the bootloader and give it information about where the application space lies for jumping and programming.  Once again this is all determined by you from your memory map and both applications' linker scripts.  You are going to need to add a separate entry inside of the linker for your CRC and length for a comparison of the calculated versus stored as well.  Whatever tool you use to append the CRC to the hex file and have it programmed to flash space, remember to note the location and make it known to the linker script so you can reference those addresses to check integrity later.

After you check everything and it is determined that it is okay to go to the application, you can use some ARM assembly to jump to the starting application address.  Before jumping, make sure to disable all peripherals and interrupts that were enabled in the bootloader.  As Colin mentioned, these will share RAM, so it is important you de-initialize all used, otherwise, you'll end up with a hard fault.

At this point, the program used another hex file laid out by a linker script, so it should begin executing as planned, as long as you have the correct vector table offset, which gets into your question fully.

As far as your question on the "Flash vector address", I think what your really mean is your interrupt vector table address.  An interrupt vector table is a data structure in memory that maps interrupt requests to the addresses of interrupt handlers.  This is where the PC register grabs the next available instruction address upon hardware interrupt triggers, for example.  You can see this by keeping track of the ARM pipeline in a few lines of assembly code.  Each entry of this table is a handler's address.  This offset must be aligned with your application, otherwise you will never go into the main function and the program will sit in the application space, but have nothing to do since all handlers addresses are unknown.   This is what the `SCB->VTOR` is for.  It is a vector interrupt table offset address register. In this case, there are a few things you can do.  Luckily, these are hard-coded inside of STM generated files inside of the file "system_stm32(xx)xx.c" (xx is your microcontroller variant).  There is a define for something called `VECT_TAB_OFFSET` which is the offset in the memory map of the vector table and is assigned to the `SCB->VTOR` register with the value that is chosen.  Your interrupt vector table will always lie at the starting address of your main application, so for the bootloader it can be `0x00`, but for the application, it will be the subtraction of the starting address of the application space, and the first addressable flash address of the microcontroller.

```c
/************************* Miscellaneous Configuration ************************/
/*!< Uncomment the following line if you need to relocate your vector Table in
     Internal SRAM. */
/* #define VECT_TAB_SRAM */
#define VECT_TAB_OFFSET  0x00 /*!< Vector Table base offset field.
                                   This value must be a multiple of 0x200. */
/******************************************************************************/
```

Make sure you understand what is expected from the micro side using STM documentation before programming things.  Vector tables in this chip can only be in multiples of `0x200`.  But to answer your question, this address can be determined by a few things.  Your memory map, and eventually, you will have a hard-coded reference to it as a define.  You can figure it out from there.

Hope this helps and good luck to you on your application.